# Subwoofer amplifier IC repair?

Tags: amplifier, soldering, speakers, repair

I bought a subwoofer as is.  The sub worked, but the speaker terminals didn't.

I took a look inside and the amplifier IC(TDA 7265) looks like it shattered somehow.

Any ideas what could have caused this?

Would it make sense to just replace it?

Also this IC is rated at 25W+25W, there's a B version that has 30W+30W can I replace it with the B version instead?[image]

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I would have changed the question to remove the repair part and **leave** the most relevant part on  design principles.."what could have caused this?"  rather than simply "put-on hold" but then not my decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old design has no current sensing or OCP and if the 2 output NPN's fail with a short circuit between Vce, then the power supply dumps all its energy into a small junction area with enough temperature rise to melt then vaporize the epoxy interface which results in enough gas pressure to explode the epoxy.
[image]

**But what causes it to overheat and create a short in the 1st place?**

My theory is it is full signal resonance with a resonant load at the unity gain frequency from some transient that triggers the oscillation.  This resonance is common to emitter followers with high Q reactive loads. The solution has always been to use a Zobel RC filter to load the driver with low R impedance load at this frequency (typ. > 100kHz).  Below shows the method of selecting C while R is normally around 8 Ohms +/-50%.  The datasheet shows this without explanation.

The circuit below courtesy of [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network) shows the optimal impedance matching method where the speaker R or DCR might be 4 Ohms for an 8 Ohm speaker.

[image]
[image][image]
There is also a series LC ferrite filter approach to this where the L ferrite is dampened with a shunt R going into 0.05uF

[image]

## Conclusion

1. Replace the IC with either version 25W or 30W with correct thermal grease.
2. Inspect for the Zobel Filter, consider adding it, if omitted.
3. Check all large e-caps with RLC meter in PS and Amp for possible ageing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the Zobel filter since that seems the most important bit.